# Background image on the entire screen not only in the middle of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, game-development

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zepXa.jpg)
Does anyone knows why my background image for the main game looks like this? I would like to set it for the entire screen, because my plan is to have different backgrounds for 2 different screens, for the menu of the game and for the game itself. If you have any idea or some input for easier my work please let me know, thanks.

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Skranji', sans-serif;
}


/* Roots */

:root {
  --background-main-game: url('../images/wowWP.jpg');
  --background-main-menu: url('../images/gameMenu.jpg');
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
}


/* Game backgound */

.mainGameBackground {
  background-image: var(--background-main-game);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="mainGameBackground">
  <!-- Game board -->
  <div class="gameBoard">
    <div class="mainBoard mt-0 mb-5 text-center mx-auto" id="mainGameBoard">
      <span id="warriorTurn"></span>
      <div class="square square1" style="border-left: 0; border-top: 0; margin-left: 15px;" id="0"></div>
      <div class="square square2" style="border-top: 0" id="1"></div>
      <div class="square square3" style="border-top: 0; border-right: 0;" id="2"></div>
      <div class="square square4" style="border-left: 0; margin-left: 15px;" id="3"></div>
      <div class="square square5" id="4"></div>
      <div class="square square6" style="border-right: 0;" id="5"></div>
      <div class="square square7" style="border-left: 0; border-bottom: 0; margin-left: 15px;" id="6"></div>
      <div class="square square8" style="border-bottom: 0;" id="7"></div>
      <div class="square square9" style="border-right: 0; border-bottom: 0;" id="8"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-md-flex">
      <button class="btn d-block mb-4 m-md-1" id="playAgain">Play Again</button>
      <button class="btn d-block ml-md-4 m-md-1" id="menuButton">Menu</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The specified width for `.mainGameBackground` should be 100vw?

Answer (score 0):

Note !!! Your Image contains white background thats why it looks like that also you must change width with 100% example bellow:

```
.mainGameBackground {
  background-image: var(--background-main-game);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%; /* width must be in percantage */
```

}

Change Image or remove white background.

Comment: The image does not has white background if i set the image on the body element the image will display on the entire screen

Comment: i think it have choose any other images and they are fiting full width.